# Check if a string contains a non alphabetic character

Tags: string, haskell, character

I have the following test case:

```
abc :: ABC 
abc = ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['a'..'z']

startState :: ABC -> String -> Maybe (String, [Char], [Char])
startState abc "Save Our Souls"  == Just ("SAVE OUR SOULS", "", "")
startState abc "Save Our Souls!" == Nothing
```

In short if the string contains a character that is not part of the abc (in the example, the third row contains a !), the function should print out nothing, otherwise it should print the string like in the example.

Here is my code:

```
startState :: ABC -> String -> Maybe (String, [Char], [Char])
startState abc "" = Just ("","","")
startState abc word = Just (word,"","")
startState abc word
 | word `elem` abc   = Just (word,"","")
 | otherwise         = Nothing
```

I get the error: `Couldn't match type Char' with` `[Char]'`

Comment: Shouldn't `abc` include a space (`' '`) as well? What exactly are the second and third item doing here in the 3-tuple?

Comment: It is a part of another subtask, it has no importance in this example.

Comment: There is [`isAlpha`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isAlpha) function in Data.Char package. Actually Data.Char is full of `isThis`, `isThat` type of character functions to distinguish various sorts of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error `Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’` because you're trying to apply `elem` to `word` which has the type `[Char]` and `abc` which has the type `[Char]` as well, while the type signature for `elem` is:

```
elem :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

So in your case you should apply it to a `Char` and a `[Char]`:

```
elem :: Char -> [Char] -> Bool
```

If you want to check if all the characters of `word` are elements of `abc`, you can use the function [`Data.List.all`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.21/base-4.11.1.0/Data-List.html#v:all) to do the following:

```
startState abc word
  | all (flip elem abc) word   = Just (word,"","")
  | otherwise                  = Nothing
```

This will apply the function `flip elem abc` to every character from `word` and return `True` when all the characters are elements of `abc`.

You should also delete these two lines:

```
startState abc "" = Just ("","","")
startState abc word = Just (word,"","")
```

as you don't need the first one and the second one is the same as the third pattern so it will make the third pattern match redundant. And you also need to add `++ [' ']` to the definition of `abc` in order to make your test case pass.

Comment: It works, thank you, but why do i need to add the `++ [' ']`?

Comment: @TylerJoe your definition of `abc` is `abc = ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['a'..'z']` so it's the list of all alphabetic characters, lower and upper cases. but you also mentioned in the questions that `startState abc "Save Our Souls"  == Just ("SAVE OUR SOULS", "", "")`. Since `"Save Our Souls"` does have the space character `' '`, you're gonna need to add it to your definition of `abc`. Try to run the code for `"Save Our Souls"` with and without adding `++ [' ']` and you'll see that you'll get `Nothing` if you don't add `++ [' ']`.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, I missed that part. Also one more question, how can I change the `abc = ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['a'..'z']` so that the lowercase and the upper case characters will be equal (the function should see 'a' as 'A' and 'A' as 'a'). I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `ABC` is a synonym of `String`, the error is from here:

```
 | word `elem` abc   = Just (word,"","")
```

`elem` has type signature of `a -> [a] -> Bool`. Since `word` and `abc` both essentially have type of `String`, this doesn't fit to the type signature of `elem`.

Since you want to test each element of `word`, this is a solution:

```
 | all (`elem` abc) word = Just (word,"","")
```

where `all` is from Prelude.

**EDIT:** Also note that `abc` is ambiguous. It is defined as a constant that has type of `ABC`, but it is also an argument for `startState`. Drop that argument:

```
abc :: ABC
abc = ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['a'..'z']

startState :: String -> Maybe (String, [Char], [Char])
startState "" = Just ("","","")
startState word
 | word `elem` abc   = Just (word,"","")
 | otherwise         = Nothing
```

Comment: I get an error: 
`Pattern match is redundant
  In an equation for startState': startState abc word` 
I think it has a problem in the otherwise case.

Comment: You should remove the line  `startState word=Just (word," "," ")` since it will always pattern match  whenever `word`is not `" "` **before** your last pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Another Alternative is to just pack it all in one function and use the function `ord` from the package `Data.Char`. The function converts characters to their decimal equivalent. By checking an ascii table you can clearly see the bounds of the characters you want. Code below:

```
conv :: String -> String
conv (x:xs) 
    | ord >= 65 && ord x <= 91  = [x] ++ conv xs
    | ord >= 97 && ord x <= 122 = [x] ++ conv xs
    | otherwise                 = "" ++ conv xs
```